# Adding language settings button to an app?

Tags: android-studio, settings, android-spinner

I want to add a spinner to my app to change the language of strings in an array list but not sure how to do so.

I made a sample app to try to change and tried couple of things but they didn't work. I know it's a basic thing but I really have no idea how to do it.

Here is the code for XML layout file

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/language_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list_item"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/list_item"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="352dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For the main activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Spinner languageSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.language_spinner);
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        /*Creating an ArrayAdapter that is populated with languagelist to populate the languageSpinner*/
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.language_list, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        /*Populating the languageSpinner with the spinnerAdapter*/
        languageSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Language changed to " + (CharSequence) languageSpinner.getSelectedItem() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("one");
        arrayList.add("two");
        arrayList.add("three");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList ) ;

        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               Resources resources = getResources();
                                        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
                                        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
                                        configuration.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("fa"));
                                        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(getIntent());
```

First of all you have to build a new string file in a new values folder in your resource folder for example i want to add persian in my app and build a value file with the name of values-fa and copy your string.xml file to it 
and change the string to the language you want .
and then you have to add this code to your spinner  `OnItemSelectedListener()`. This work for me.